# How to code an UI button(with Exit funtion) for an Android device in Unity 3D(C#)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner of Unity 3D. I am writing an android app, and my start menu has an exit button. My idea is just very simple: after users press the exit button, the application will close.

I know Application.Quit() for quiting an app. But I just dont know how to detect a touch from user on a button and return the application.quit() method. Should I use sth like button.onclick or input.getTouch?

This is my code:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class ExitButton : MonoBehaviour {

    public Button exitButton;

    void Start()
    {
        Button btn = exitButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        Debug.Log("You touched this button.");
    }
    }
```

After I tried to play my app, I get this error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ExitButton.Start()
```

And it seems that I cant get signal from user touching the button.

Can someone give me a help?

I have linked my button in inspector, but i am not able to find my function name:TaskOnClick()
[Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3WFJ.png)

Comment: Show us your attempts at trying to implement this, and any problems you've come across. As it currently stands, this question can be answered by a simple visit to Google.

Comment: I have watched many videos, but I cant find one which meets my need.

Comment: [Try this one.](https://www.google.be/search?q=unity+android+button+click+event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple you have problem with access modifiers to fix this just type

```
public void TaskOnClick()
{
 Application.Quit ();
}
```

check this video it's will help you create a professional gui.

[How to make a professional GUI using unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jc9iLhZWdk)

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code into a script

```
public void QuitGame()
{
    Application.Quit();
}
```

attach the script to a game object then assign the button to a method using the OnClick window at the bottom of the button component in the inspector.

Attach the game object to the OnClick and choose the QuitGame function.

Note. This will only work in the build of the game and not in the editor.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works on my phone. But I have a question: when I play the app on Unity 3D on my computer, the error"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ExitButton.Start()" still occurs, but since the quit button is work on my android phone. Does it mean that this error is not important?(no need to beware of it)

Comment: See @ZayedUpal response, he explains it well.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up between two methods of using a button.
If you are following @Jack Foulkes's method then you don't need to assign the button externally. That means you don't need the following code:

```
public Button exitButton;

void Start()
{
    Button btn = exitButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
}
```

If you use the above code, then you don't need to add **OnClick** event listener in inspector, as you are already adding it inside your code.
 Only your code will work. You are getting the null reference, because you haven't assigned the **exitButton** from inspector actually.
It should look like this in the inspector:
[inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgvWQ.jpg)

Comment: "You are getting the null reference, because you haven't assigned the exitButton from inspector actually." 
Yes, I made this silly mistake. Thank you very much Zayed. It works now.! :)

Comment: My Pleasure :).
Would be a great help, if you upvote it :P.

Comment: @GarethLam you should accept the answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script with the following contents and then attach it to the corresponding button click

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ExitButton : MonoBehaviour {
    public void ExitGame()
    {
        print("Exiting...");
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello**,
All you need to do is to just make this function **Public**

*like this*:

```
public void TaskOnClick() 
{
   Application.Quit(); 
}
```

---

**You Can Also make an if statement to make it much better :)**

***FOR EXAMPLE***:

```
public void TaskOnClick() 
    {
      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) // You Can also change the key
      {
       Application.Quit(); 
}
    }
```

---

**And If you want to make it less effort *MAKE* a Function**

***TRY THIS***:

```
   public void ExitFunction()
{
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) // Or Any Other Key
   {
     Application.Quit();
     Debug.Log("exitgame");
   }
} 
   Public void TaskOnClick() 
        {
           ExitFunction();
        }
```

---

**And Also Here is the code if you want to make the same function but on the *left Mouse Button Click***

```
public void ExitFunction()
{
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
   {
       Application.Quit();
       Debug.Log("exitgame");
   }
}
public void TaskOnClick() 
{
   ExitFunction();
}
```

---

**If you want it with the *Right Mouse Button***

**Here is the *Answer:***

```
public void ExitFunction()
{
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
   {
      Application.Quit();
      Debug.Log("quitgame");
   }
}
public void TaskOnClick() 
{
   ExitFunction();
}
```

---

**If you want it but with the middle button
Here is the *Answer:***

```
public void ExitFunction()
{
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
   {
      Application.Quit();
      Debug.Log("quitgame");
   }
}
public void TaskOnClick() 
{
   ExitFunction();
}
```

---

***Full Best Code:***

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 
 public class ExitButton : MonoBehaviour
 {

    public void ExitFunction()
    {
       if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
       {
          Application.Quit();
          Debug.Log("quitgame");
       }
    }
    public void TaskOnClick() 
    {
       ExitFunction();
    }
    }
```

---

> Lesson Summary:

-- Sometimes Use ***public*** when we need it like when we use ***GameObjects*** and ***Transforms*** for example.

-- if () statement is used to make the I.D.E understands the very **specific objects** like **Do an action when .... is pressed.**

Thank you.

---

**Hope This Helped**

Eyad ,
A Professional Game Developer & Front End Web Developer

Answer (score -1):

Do you link your button in inspector?

EDIT.
I think this should be changed also:

```
void TaskOnClick()
{
     Debug.Log("You touched this button.");
     Application.Quit (); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I linked my button in inspector, but I couldnt find my function name(TaskOnClick())  in the "On Click ()" part.